# how to speed up CABasicAnimation?

Tags: ios, cabasicanimation

I am using the following CABasicAnimation. But, its very slow..is there a way to speed it up ? Thanks.

```
- (void)spinLayer:(CALayer *)inLayer duration:(CFTimeInterval)inDuration
 direction:(int)direction
{
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;

// Rotate about the z axis
 rotationAnimation = 
[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];

// Rotate 360 degress, in direction specified
 rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 * direction];

// Perform the rotation over this many seconds  
rotationAnimation.duration = inDuration;

// Set the pacing of the animation
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = 
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

// Add animation to the layer and make it so
[inLayer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried giving it a smaller duration? Or are you wondering about framerate?

Comment: @Yann : Thanks that works. But, if I want a longer duration what do I do ? I am using 10 seconds now, But I need the animation for 80 seconds or so....any help ?

Comment: Then give it a duration of 80 seconds...

Comment: @Yann : But, with duration 80, the spins is very slow !.. Thats why had to change the duration to 10 (as per your advice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Animation animations can repeat a number of times, by setting the repeatCount property on the animation.

So if you'd like to have an animation run for a total 80 seconds, you need to figure out a duration for one pass of the animation – maybe one full spin of this layer – and then set the duration to be that value. Then let the animation repeat that full spin several times to fill out your duration.

So something like this:

```
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 8.0;
```

Alternatively, you can use repeatDuration to achieve a similar affect:

```
rotationAnimation.repeatDuration = 80.0;
```

In either case, you need to set the duration to the time of a single spin, and then repeat it using ONE of these methods. If you set both properties, the behavior is undefined. You can check out the documentation on CAMediaTiming [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html).